# Fastest way to loop through jQuery-returned DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, dom, nodes

I got a very interesting, yet absolutely logical result while chilling on jsperf.

http://jsperf.com/for-in-jquery-return-value-vs-jquery-each

*In a preparation environment, where `O` is jQuery return value of 200 DOM Nodes, and `a` is an empty array,*

```
O.each(function() {
  a[a.length] = $(this).text();
});
```

is a LOT slower than this "pure" snippet

```
for (i = 0; i < O.length; i++) {
  a[a.length] = O[i].text();
}
```

( For the difference, check the link above )

Considering, that I was just having fun, there have to be even faster ways out there.
What is the fastest way to loop through DOM elements using jQuery?

Comment: At the end of the day, jQuery also uses JavaScript functionality so it makes sense that "vanilla" JavaScript would be faster than any framework/plugins built on top of it.

Comment: You are absolutely right, Lix, but jQuery's return array is designed to work well with the jQuery methods. That's why I am surprised, that a tricky way like this is faster than their own loop method.

Comment: Your MAIN performance loss will come from the excessive use of `$(this)`. As stated by @Lix, no jQuery way of doing things can possibly be faster than plain JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well performed another test, seems that

http://jsperf.com/for-in-jquery-return-value-vs-jquery-each/2

```
for (i = 0; i < O.length; i++) {
  a[a.length] = O[i].text(); // tested this, because this is the usual way i work with pushing item to array
}
```

is even faster than -

```
for (i = 0; i < O.length; i++) {
  a.push($(O[i]).text());
}
```

I guess `push` itself is slower or removing extra `$(..)`, removes some overhead.

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: Actually, I was not really looking for a .push replacement, but Your answer here might be pretty useful. Removing `$()` was a very good idea. Thank You for Your effort.

Comment: Interesting, they differ slightly. And sometimes overlap. For example, in chrome check the graph, but firefox, it's a different story. Lol.

Comment: It is very interesting indeed. I would appreciate an explanation from someone.

Comment: Did you also note that, in performance, Chrome 35 was faster than both Chrome 36 and FireFox 30.